# Klein $4$-group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Let $G$ be a permutation group on $X$ and let $\overline{X} = X\cup {a}$, where
$a\notin X$. A transitive permutation group $\overline{G}$ on $\overline{X} $ is a transitive extension of $G$ if $G\le \overline{G}$ and $Stab_{\overline{G}}(a)=G$.

I am trying to prove the following statement:

**The Klein $4$-group $\langle (12)(34),(13)(24)\rangle$ has no transitive extension.**

I tried some directions for solving this statement, but I could not. Actually, I don't know what is the best approach for solving this question.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What makes an extension transitive? (I'm just curious.)

Comment: What does "transitive" mean in this context? is its related to the extension?  or maybe as a subgroup of some permutation group? Could you add the definition of it?

Comment: I have edited my question!

Comment: Have you perhaps left off a condition? Namely that the result of restricting of the action of $\bar G$ on $\bar X$ to an action of $G$ on $X$ is equal to the given action of $G$ on $X$.

Comment: @LeeMosher: The action of $G$ on $X$ is the same as the action of $\overline{G}$ on $\overline{X}$. The mentioned definition is exactly what I have seen in the book "An introduction to the theory of groups", by J. Rotman.

Comment: You have said what it means for a permutation group to have a transitive extension. But the Klein 4-group is an abstract group, not a permutation group. So for the problem to make sense, you need to specify a permutation group that is isomorphic to the Klein 4-group, There do exist transitive permutation groups in which the stabilizer is isomorphic to the Klein 4-group, There is one of degree $9$, for example.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I think we can consider the Klein $4$-group as $\langle (12)(34),(13)(24)\rangle$. Am I right?

Comment: Why are you asking me if you are right? You are the one asking the question!

Comment: @DerekHolt: Sorry. I was worried about my misunderstanding about the last line of your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, let's assume that $G = \langle (1,2)(3,4), (1,3)(2,4) \rangle \le S_4$. We want to prove that there exists no group $X \le S_5$ with the stabilizer $X_5$ of $5$ equal to $G$.

We would have $|X|=20$ and hence by Sylow's theorem $X$ has a normal Sylow $5$-subgroup $P$, which must be generated by a $5$-cycle $x=(a,b,c,d,5)$, where $a,b,c,d$ is some permutation of $1,2,3,4$. But the only element of order $2$ in $S_5$ that fixes $5$ and normalizes $P$ is $(a,d)(b,c)$ (which conjugates $x$ to $x^{-1}$), so $P$ cannot be normalized by each of the three involutions in $G$, contradiction.